# how to get pdf file's last write date from char*(the file is in memory)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

i want to get the pdf file's last write date as a timestamp, but the pdf file is in memory, pointed by a char*.

in the middle of this code, you can see all file segments downloaded and assembled/stored in a char* *packet*, i want get the pdf file's info from *packet*:

```
void ProcessSegmt(const uint8 *pSeg, uint32 iSegLen)
{
    char* pFile;
    char* packet = m_packet_;
    if( iSegLen != 0 ) // flush work buffers
    {
        if ( offset == 0 )
        {
            memset(header, 0, sizeof header);
            pFile = strstr (GetFilename(), "\x5C"); //finds \ for directory
            sprintf(header, "\t%s\t%d\t", ++pFile, nDownloadFileSize);

            memset(packet, 0, MAX_BUF+MAX_HEADER);
            memcpy(packet, header, strlen(header));
        }

        if ( offset + iSegLen < nDownloadFileSize ) // part of file downloaded 
        {
            memcpy( packet+strlen(header) + offset, pSeg, iSegLen );
            offset += iSegLen;

            Logger->root()->info("Downloaded file: %s, already %d bytes, left %d bytes", 10, GetFilename(), offset, 
                nDownloadFileSize - offset);
        }
        else if ( offset + iSegLen == nDownloadFileSize )
        {
            // all downloaded
            memcpy( packet+strlen(header)+offset, pSeg, iSegLen );
            offset = 0;

            Logger->root()->info("Downloaded entire contents of file: %s", 10, GetFilename());

            // !!!!!!!
            // all segements downloaded(in packet), i want get timestamp here 
            // !!!!!!!

        }
        else
        {
            offset = 0; 
            Logger->root()->info("Error downloading file: %s", 11, GetFilename());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Information like the last edit time, creation time and other file-related information are not stored *within* the files contents but by the respective filesystem (as for example a header).

Therefore you have no chance of getting this information from only the contents of the file, except you know the format of the file and this format contains the information.

Comment: that is a pdf file, sorry i forget mention that, you mean pdf file have it's own format of header?

Comment: Yes, see the PDF file format specification to find out if it contains the information you want, and then use the format to read it. ;)

Comment: you mean function like *BOOL WINAPI GetFileTime(...)* can identify file type, then invoke different parse function to parse different header?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724320(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ... no it can't because it only works for an *existing file* on your hard drive.. if you only have the content, you can NOT get the file time without somehow parsing the content for that info.